# Iteratively assigning unique ID in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have the problem of iterating through a Pandas DataFrame, which consists of 200.000 rows. Each row consists of sentences of varying lengths, which I wish to split up on special characters, as can be seen in the re.split method.

What I wish to do is to keep track of which sentences got split into how many sub-sentences by assigning them a unique ID.

What I have now is:

```
lengths = []
reviews = []
for sentence in corpus:
    subsentence = re.split(r'[.|,|?|!]', str(sentence))
    for i in review:
        lengths.append(len(review))
        reviews.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame({'review':reviews,'length': lengths})
```

[picture of resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk741.png)

What I want is for the sentences who are split into multiple sub-sentences to share a unique ID, such that I can glue them together again.

Comment: Can you add some sample data for `corpus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lengths = []
reviews = []
unique_ids = []
unique_id = 0
for sentence in corpus:
    review = re.split(r'[.|,|?|!]', str(sentence)) #assuming here that subsentences == review
    for i in review:
        lengths.append(len(review))
        reviews.append(i)
        unique_ids.append(unique_id)
    unique_id += 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'review':reviews,'length': lengths, 'unique_ids': unique_ids})
```